# how to get char* filename from boost path

Tags: boost

```
for (fs::directory_iterator iter(realPath); iter != end_iter; ++iter )
        {
            if (iter->path().extension() == ".png"){
                fs::path currentPath = iter->path();
                const char *filename = const_cast<char*>(currentPath.string().c_str());
                std::cout << iter->path().leaf() << std::endl;

                processFile(filename);
                std::cout <<"Hi" << std::endl;
            }
        }
```

This is my code and here processFile functions accepts the filename in char* format. Above code returns a junk value of filename. Don't know what is the best way to get the filename.

Comment: Why are you casting on this line? `const char *filename = const_cast<char*>(currentPath.string().c_str());` c_str() returns a const char* for you... i.e. `const char* filename = currentPath.string().c_str()`

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me here (Boost.1.52, Mac OS X, clang).

Though I have to agree with Miguel, you're doing way to much work here.

```
for (fs::directory_iterator iter(realPath); iter != end_iter; ++iter )
    if (iter->path().extension() == ".png") {
        fs::path currentPath = iter->path();
        std::cout << currentPath.leaf() << std::endl;
        processFile(currentPath.c_str ());
    }
```

and depending on your taste in code, you could get rid of `currentPath` altogether ( replace it with `iter->path()` )